# How to set time interval when hitting keyboard for autoComplete?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, autocomplete

AutoComplete Populating will repond to each key typing for when you input data in AutoComplete.

Is it posssible to set time interval to respond key typing?

For example, set MinimumPrefixLength=3 for an AutoComplete. If user input "School" in the box with within 3 seconds and time interval is set as 5 second, then Populating event only fired one time, otherwise it will be fired 3 times, if  Populating connect to async call, that will be a big issue for performance.

Comment: Find out solution: there is property MinimumPopulateDelay available for this purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `MinimumPopulateDelay` property not acheive your goal?